# Get error string from jQuery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've an ajax call and I need to get the error shown on chrome console

```
 GET file://accesstoken%23access_token%3D12*ee182aec46fd85ea59a4da481c65/ net::ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT
```

How can I get this message?

```
 $.ajax({
 url: "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=e40f15a**9851d8a66&redirect_uri=file://accesstoken&response_type=token",

success:function(result,status,xhr){

 },

 error: function(data){
console.log(data);


 }   

 });
```

I've tried with error callback but with console.log data I can't find this message

Comment: This probably means the HTTPS page you're requesting is sending you to another domain, or a non-HTTPS page.

Comment: Yes I know. I would get this errormessage as a string.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I think actually, the issue is that you're passing the querystring through the `url` attribute and what jQuery is doing, is finishing it off with a `/`, because it will try and append the `data` attribute to the end of the `url`

Comment: How can I get the error message shown in chrome console?

Comment: you can't, because it is an HTTP error

Comment: why are you redirecting to the file protocol?

Comment: jQuery isn't producing an error.

Comment: It is a OAuth authentication.The server redirect me to a url choise from me. I need to get this url but I don't know how!!

Comment: mixing http and file protocol is not a good fix.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your `URL` has the query parameters inside it. I don't think jQuery works like that, so I propose this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize",
    data: { "client_id": "e40f15a**9851d8a66", "redirect_uri": "file://accesstoken", "response_type": "token" },

    success: function (result, status, xhr) {

    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Secondly, the browser is display an HTTP error, not to be displayed in the console.

The line:

```
console.log(data);
```

Will show the error in the console.

I have also looked at Instagrams authorisation [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) and it states the URL end point is:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
```

**UPDATE**

Just checked with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6YBVS/), it is possible to send the entire URL and query string just through the `url` property, however, it may be more beneficial in certain circumstances to break up the request like i've done.

This is especially true in the case that what if the URL changed, or you were using a sandbox URL

Comment: A url can have querystring parameters, there is not rule against that.  It should be url encoded...

Comment: from what I have read, jQuery makes no mention of whether you can pass a full query string through the `url` property. From the URL that the OP got return, it looks as though jQuery added a `/` to the end of it

Comment: The url should have been `....redirect_uri=file%3A%2F%2Faccesstoken%26response_type%3Dtoken` which is what the data will do.